# Clear local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

My online store uses local storage to store the cart. After the user has checked out, I want to clear it. However, `localstorage.clear();` isn't working for me.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#matkahuolto").live('click', function() {
        $(".maksu").slideDown(600);
        $("#matkahuolto").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
        $("#posti").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#matkahuolto").addClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
        $("#posti").removeClass( "selectedtoimitus" );
        $(".simpleCart_shipping").html("15.00€");   
        localstorage.clear()


    });
 });
```

Comment: `window.localStorage.clear()`?

Comment: [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) -- [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Familiarize yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct spelling is [`localStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) - Javascript is case-sensitive:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

If this doesn't work because of a local variable, you'd need to use `window.localStorage`.

Comment: My problem was I called my function "reset()", renamed it and worked afterwards. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
  localstorage.clear()
       ^
      here is the problem it must be in uppercase use below 


localStorage.clear();
```

or

```
window.localStorage.clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
window.localStorage.clear()
```

The context of your handler may be affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

It's `localStorage` - make sure you uppercase the S otherwise it doesn't refer to the same thing. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Actually I found `localstorage.clear();` on stackoverflow... but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using .one ensures this is done only once and not repeatedly.

```
    $(window).one("focus", function() {
        localStorage.clear();
    });
```

It is okay to put several document.ready event listeners (if you need other events to execute multiple times) as long as you do not overdo it, for the sake of readability.

.one is especially useful when you want local storage to be cleared only once the first time a web page is opened or when a mobile application is installed the first time.

```
// Fired once when document is ready
 $(document).one('ready', function () {
   localStorage.clear();
 });
```